# Width - fifty per cent for table cell display breaks into seperate line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a panel that displays information in a tabular fashion as,
[image]

My pluker code is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/I46WvANQpKuO2G2vT7JY?p=preview). Now, i use `display:table-row` to put `NAME` label and value `My Venue` in one place. When i give 50% width to the `table-cell` display, it breaks into next line as,

[image]

I am able to fix it by making the width as 49% for `table-cell` display.

I am curious why does `50%` width break it into a different line, since `table` display doesn't have any margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's whitespace between the two spans. That whitespace is rendered as a space, the space has a nonzero width. After 50% plus the width of a space, there isn't room for another 50%, so the second span wraps. If you butt the `</span><span>` right against each other with no whitespace in between, the wrapping goes away. There are [other ways to deal with the problem](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), including adjusting the font-size to 0 so that the space will have zero width, or using other methods for layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use a responsive grid system like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnp6myu8/)

```css
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF TWO  */
.span_2_of_2 {
 width: 100%;
}
.span_1_of_2 {
 width: 49.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col { 
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .span_2_of_2, .span_1_of_2 { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="section group">
 <div class="col span_1_of_2">
 My Name
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_2">
 My Venue
 </div>
</div>
```